# No se porque no me muestras la imagen <img src="{{asset('storage').'/'.$Equipo->foto}}" width="80px" height="80px"> en mi vitas Laravel

Tags: laravel

si me los esta aguardando en la base de datos y en la carpeta storage/app/storage/public/uploads pero no lo puedo visualizar en mi vista.

```
<img src="{{asset('storage').'/'.$Equipo->foto}}"  width="80px" height="80px">
```

si me los mostraba y de la nada dejo de hacerlo, ya intente de varias formas y nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Generaste el [link simbolico](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)? Que hay en '$Equipo->foto'? El directorio que mencionas 'storage/app/storage/public/uploads' no coincide con el que muestras en la imagen... Cual es el directorio real?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ  genere el link php artisan storage:link , me corría bien podía visualizar las imágenes pero de repente me dejo de mostrarlas, de hecho tengo dos vistas la cual no se relacionan en nada y en las dos me dejo de mostrar las imágenes, ya borre la cache pensando que era eso pero nada

Comment: Primero probaría volver a generar el link simbólico. Si no es eso tendrías que debugar un poco para ver la url que estás generando. En la imagen se ve un directorio `uploads` que en el código no está, salvo que esté en esa variable, por eso te preguntaba que valor hay ahí

Answer (score 0):

storage/app/storage/public/uploads

storage/app/storage/app/public/uploads

puedes ejecutar un {{dd(asset('storage')."/".$Equipo->foto)}} para comparar la ruta que te muestra y si es la correcta a tu imagen